# Import Orders from different database to wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My old website built using php+mysql and current website using wordpress
now i want to migrate all the orders from old website to new wordpress website

how can I proceed please suggest me something??

Comment: You need to create a map between the tables in two database, which is definitely not an easy task and then transfer data. I don't know either system, either your old website or if wordpress has such an ordering model or plugin but it requires a lot manual work.

Comment: you should google it.. it is really not that hard and there is plenty of answers...

Comment: @smozgur I know lot of manual work is there ok let me try thanx for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

You can try out some plugins listed here :

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-csvimport/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/

**NOTE : Please checkout the format maintain by the plugins**

Thanks and Regards